# C++ code problem

Tags: c++

I am having some problem with this code. I am trying to display...
12345
12345
12345

but I am getting an error saying...

> Error  1   error C3861: 'displayOneRowOfDesign1': identifier not found

can anyone help?

```
// displays (on the screen) design1 
void displayDesign1 ()
{
  system ("cls"); // clears the screen

  // the entire for loop displays all three rows 
  for (int r = 1; r <= 3; r++)
  { // One iteration of the body of this loop displays row number r.
    // In other words, when r is 1, row 1 is displayed; 
    //                 when r is 2, row 2 is displayed; ...
    displayOneRowOfDesign1 ();
  }

} // displayDesign1  


// displays one row of design1; helper function to displayDesign1 
void displayOneRowOfDesign1 ()
{
  // the entire for loop displays all the columns of the row
  for (int c=1; c <= 5; c++)
  { // One iteration of this loop displays the symbol in column c
    // In other is case, when c is 1, a 1 is displayed; 
    //                   when c is 2, a 2 is displayed; ...
    cout << c;
  }

  cout << endl; // wraps up the row 
                // by sending the cursor to the next row (line)

} // displayOneRowOfDesign1
```

Comment: C++ uses a single pass compiler.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding

```
void displayOneRowOfDesign1();
```

to the top of your code. This is called a "forward declaration" and is necessary because you are attempting to call that function before you have defined it.

Comment: Now I have this and I am getting another error saying...Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

Comment: That's a little hard to debug without knowing your setup. Are you using Visual Studio? If so, is this supposed to be a console application?

Comment: Yeah I am using Visual Studio and yeah its supposed to be a console application

Comment: Then you must have two things: first, you must define a main() function, and then under project settings you need to set the type to a console application. I don't exactly recall where this setting is, it might be a linker setting.

Answer (score 4):

C++ is rather old fashioned and needs to know about things before they are used.  Cut and paste displayOneRowOfDesign1 so that it's above the first function.

Comment: Yes, +1. If these functions were members of a class definition it wouldn't be an issue, but the way you present your code they look like free-standing functions. If that is the case, then yes, you need to define/use them in just the same way as you would a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler reads your code top to bottom; at the time it's parsing `displayDesign1`, which calls `displayOneRowOfDesign1`, it doesn't know that `displayOneRowOfDesign1` exists.

Either move `displayOneRowOfDesign1` above `displayDesign1`, or put the [prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) at the top before the function definitions (you can think of it as a promise to the compiler that a function with that signature will be defined later):

```
void displayOneRowOfDesign1();

// Your function definitions...
```